# Where can I find sample code for integrating iAds within my application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm just starting to learn how to integrate iAds within my application.  I have read all of the documentation on this provided by Apple, but I still have some questions about the process.  Is there any sample code or better documentation out there that shows how to place iAds within an application?

Comment: Maybe you should revisit your old questions and accept the best answers? This site is not a one way street that writes your apps...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll find any public sample code for this until Apple lifts the NDA on iOS 4, and even then it might take a while.

In the meantime, you should watch Session 112 - Integrating Ads with iAd from the freely available [WWDC 2010 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).